# What do show and render do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

For example, in this code:

```
module Main(letters) where

import Data.List(nub)

import qualified Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ as PP
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ(Doc,text,int,(<>),(<+>),($+$),render)

data Prop a = 
     LetterP a
   | AndP (Prop a) (Prop a)
 deriving Eq

class PPLetter a where
  ppLetter :: a -> Doc

instance PPLetter Int where
  ppLetter a = text ("p"++show a)

instance PPLetter Char where
  ppLetter = PP.char

instance PPLetter a => PPLetter [a] where
  ppLetter = PP.hcat . (map ppLetter)

class PP a where
  pp :: a -> Doc

instance PP Bool where
  pp True = text "True"
  pp False = text "False"

parens n (term@(LetterP _)) = pp term

instance PPLetter a => PP(Prop a) where   
  pp (LetterP a) = ppLetter a
  pp (AndP x y) = PP.sep [ parens 4 x, text "/\\", parens 4 y]

instance PPLetter a => Show (Prop a) where
  show x = render (pp x)

main = do
    let p = LetterP 1
    print p
```

Comment: Please be a bit more verbose when posing a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [The Show class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aShow), and its method, `show`, convert values to Strings.
2. The [render](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/latest/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html#v%3arender) function is part of the `Text.PrettyPrint` module, which converts values to prettily printed strings (e.g. with layout, indenting and nesting).

Together they are used for [pretty printing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/latest/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html)